# How to make launchscreen.storyboard support portrait and landscape

Tags: ios, objective-c

I use LaunchScreen.storyboard as my launch image. It works ok when the devices are portrait. When i launch the app on landscape mode on ipad or iphone7 plus whe image was stretched.How can i use two different image for portrait and landscape mode. 
Thank you.

Comment: Can't reproduce this, can you say size of image and image constraints(if you have them)?

Comment: I only have one image(2208 × 1242).The  LaunchScreen.storyboard only have one imageview and fill the viewcontroller. When i launch the app on landscape the image will be stretched.

Comment: What have you set the image content mode to? Aspect fill?  Aspect fit?

Comment: The point is how to set two different image for portrait and landscape on LaunchScreen.storyboard.Thank you.

Comment: Did you find a solution?

Answer (score 3):

You can set another image based on the size class traits. Unfortunately this does not help with left and right landscape rotation (you can only have an image for one of them). Also it is kind of base on the fact that for current iPhones landscape can be detected by having a compact height trait. This may change in future.

[image]